# Flutter resize DecoratedBox on validate error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a `DecoratedBox` to add a background to my `TextFormField`. 
However, after using the `validator` for error scenario, the `DecoratedBox` expands to accommodate the error message which pushes the background color outside the bounds of the `TextFormField`. Is there a way to prevent it from happening.

[image]

```
final lastNameBox =  DecoratedBox(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color(0x2B8E8E93),
      borderRadius:BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: const Radius.circular(24.0),
          topRight: const Radius.circular(24.0),
          bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(24.0),
          bottomRight: const Radius.circular(24.0))),
  child: firstName,

);


    final firstName = TextFormField(
      controller: _firstNameController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
     validator: Validator.validateFirstName,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'First Name',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the background color always wraps the `TextFormField` for all scenarios. 
Ideally, I would like to have just the error in red color appear below the `TextFormField` without any `background` color to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `DecoratedBox` widget and modify `firstName` widget like:

```
final firstName = TextFormField(
      controller: _firstNameController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
     validator: Validator.validateFirstName,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'First Name',
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Color(0x2B8E8E93),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );
```